# Knight's Repair Ability in Elder Scrolls Arena

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-arena

I started playing Elder Scrolls Arena again with a new character, this time a Knight due to their ability allowing them to auto repair their equipment and also being immune to paralysis.

Could anyone explain to me how the repairing ability works? I have some magical items (belts, torcs, crystals) but I don't see them getting repaired. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have little experience with Arena, therefore not an answer. But in Daggerfall, magic items cannot be repaired at all unless you change a specific ini-setting. It is possible the same thing applies to Arena.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The repairing ability for the [Knight](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Arena:Knight#Knight) is for *equipment* that is, armor and weapons - *not* magically enchanted gear.

> They also have **the ability to repair damaged weapons or armor**. This
>   ability is done automatically to any weapons or armor in their
>   inventory.
>
> Special: Immune to Paralysis; **Automatically repair damaged weapons or
>   armor**; 25% Lockpick Effectiveness

The magical items need to be recharged, not repaired. A way to do this is at the [Blacksmith](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Arena:Services).

> Blacksmiths can also repair weapons, armor, and **charged magic items
>   (marks, crystals, bracers, rings, and artifacts)**.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very good answer. Now I understand why my weapons and armor are always in good condition, but not my magical items.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that charges from enchanted armor and weapons get recharged whenever the kinght's repair ability kicks in. As mentioned before, this does not happen with non-armor/weapon equipment such as amulets, torcs, etc.